# How to create regExp pattern only for text

Tags: javascript

How would I create a `RegEx` pattern only for text. I have some code but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
document.myform.firstname.onchange = function() {
    var pattern = new RegExp("\\a-z+", "i");
    var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;

    if (!(isValid)) { 
        alert("error"); 
    } else { 
        alert("fine"); 
    } 
};
```

Comment: You probably mean `/[a-z]+/i`. How did you confuse that with `\\a-z`?

Comment: document.myform.firstname.onchange= function() {
        var pattern = new RegExp("\\[a-z]+", "i");
        var isValid = this.value.search(pattern) >= 0;
        
        if (!(isValid)) {
            alert("error");
        } else {
            alert("fine");
        }
        
    };

Comment: Provide additional details by [edit]ing your question, not by putting unformatted code in comments.

Comment: Xufox thanks a lot, now it works properly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given regex in your OP will match the string `\a-z`, you have to use `/[a-z]+/i` as mentioned in the comment so your code will :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\[a-z]+", "i");
```

Instead of :

```
var pattern = new RegExp("\\a-z+", "i");
```

Hoep this helps.

```js
//Old regex
var pattern = new RegExp("\\a-z+", "i");
console.log('11\a-z11'.search(pattern)>=0); //true
console.log('1111'.search(pattern)>=0); //false
console.log('11a11'.search(pattern)>=0); //false

console.log('----------'); 

//New regex
var pattern = new RegExp("\[a-z]+", "i");
console.log('1111'.search(pattern)>=0); //false
console.log('11a11'.search(pattern)>=0); //true
```